# PHP - preg_match - assign arbitrary value to a matched element

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pipe

assuming we have this regex:

```
preg_match('/\b(xbox|xbox360|360|pc|ps3|wii)\b/i' , $string, $matches);
```

now, whenever the regex match for ex. *one of the three xbox methods (xbox|xbox360|360)*, the `$matches`, should return just **XBOX**

is this possible continuing to work in the `preg_match()` context or i should use some other method?

thank's in advance.

**EDITED:**

im actually doing it like this:

```
$x = array('xbox360','xbox','360');
if( preg_match('/\b(xbox360|xbox|360|pc|ps3)\b/i', $s, $m ) ) {
  $t = $m[0];
}
if ( in_array($t,$x) ) {
  $t = 'XBOX';
}
```

i'm wondering if there is another way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your current code looks ok to me, if you want it a bit fancier, you can try named subpatterns

```
preg_match('/\b((?P<XBOX>xbox|xbox360|360)|pc|ps3|wii)\b/i' , $string, $matches);
$t = isset($matches['XBOX']) ? 'XBOX' : $matches[0];
```

or preg_replac'ing things before matching:

```
$string = preg_replace('~\b(xbox|xbox360|360)\b~', 'XBOX', $string);
preg_match('/\b(XBOX|pc|ps3|wii)\b/i' , $string, $matches);
```

on big inputs i guess your method would be the fastest. A minor improvement would be to replace `in_array` with a hash-based lookup:

```
$x = array('xbox360' => 1,'xbox' => 1,'360' => 1);
if( preg_match('/\b(xbox360|xbox|360|pc|ps3)\b/i', $s, $m ) ) {
  $t = $m[0];
}
if ( isset($x[$t] ) {
  $t = 'XBOX';
}
```

named subpatterns: see http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php, example 3

Comment: tnx y very much, your regex rocks! ;) can you explane the (?P<XBOX>xbox|xbox360|360) part?

Comment: tnx a lot, i will do! ;) i liked the use of isset() instead of in_array().

Comment: ah, and another thing... your first add '/\b((?P<XBOX>xbox|xbox360|360)|pc|ps3|wii)\b/i' is the one that ask the question (for people that may have the same needs)!